# Fatal devappserver2 error: PYTHON_EGG_CACHE in Appengine 1.7.6 and 1.7.5 python 2.7, win7

Tags: google-app-engine, windows-7, python-2.7

I attempted to use Appengine SDK version 1.7.6 but was receiving fatal errors (same as outlined below) so reverted to 1.7.5, where my app works fine. However, the errors I saw in 1.7.6 recur when I attempt to run the experimental devappserver in 1.7.5.  I am running Python 2.7 on a win 7 machine. Standard install selections for AppEngine.

These error messages refer to permissions relating to the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE, but...
- 1) They do not occur for the 'old' dev_appserver
- 2) The application can successfully extract files to the location noted.  In fact, I changed the path of the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE to another location, gave it wide open permissions, and still received the error.
- 3) I have pyyaml in my site-packages, so am not sure why it would need to do a temporary extract anyway.

Any help looking for a resolution to this would be appreciated, since I'll be forced to use the new devappserver in a couple of releases time.

Command line error dump below:

```
python "C:\Program Files (x
86)\Google\google_appengine\devappserver2.py" .
WARNING  2013-03-25 19:10:41,029 devappserver2.py:497] devappserver2.py is curre
ntly experimental but will eventually replace dev_appserver.py in the App Engine
 Python SDK. For more information and to report bugs, please see: http://code.go
ogle.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/
INFO     2013-03-25 19:10:41,171 appcfg.py:618] Checking for updates to the SDK.

WARNING  2013-03-25 19:10:44,525 simple_search_stub.py:975] Could not read searc
h indexes from c:\users\ben\appdata\local\temp\appengine.dev~upskillme-main.Ben\
search_indexes
INFO     2013-03-25 19:10:44,539 api_server.py:148] Starting API server at: http
://localhost:49302
INFO     2013-03-25 19:10:44,555 dispatcher.py:96] Starting server "default" run
ning at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-03-25 19:10:44,571 admin_server.py:112] Starting admin server at:
http://localhost:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\_python_runtime.py", line
 150, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\_python_runtime.py", line
 146, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
vappserver2\python\runtime.py", line 39, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remo
te_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 75, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml-3.10\yaml\__init
__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cyaml import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml-3.10\yaml\cyaml.
py", line 5, in <module>
    from _yaml import CParser, CEmitter
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyyaml-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg\_yaml.py", lin
e 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyyaml-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg\_yaml.py", lin
e 4, in __bootstrap__
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 882, in resource_f
ilename
    self, resource_name
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 1351, in get_resou
rce_filename
    self._extract_resource(manager, self._eager_to_zip(name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 1406, in _extract_
resource
    manager.extraction_error()  # report a user-friendly error
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 928, in extraction
_error
    raise err
pkg_resources.ExtractionError: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

  [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Ben\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python-Eggs\\py
yaml-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg-tmp\\_yaml.pyd'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

  C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\Python-Eggs

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.

Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
vappserver2\server.py", line 1045, in _loop_adjusting_instances
    self._adjust_instances()
```

Comment: I'd recommend reporting this in the appropriate group to make sure it gets seen: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/appengine-devappserver2-discuss

Answer (score 2):

If anyone comes along with the same issue, the resolution that worked for me was as follows:

- Unzip the PyYAML-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg in your python27 site-packages
  directory into a new directory within site-packages.  You'll need to
  unzip it to into a directory name like NEWPyYAML-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg
  to avoid name conflicts.
- Rename your original egg. to something else (e.g.,  OLDPyYAML-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg).
- Rename your new directory to PyYAML-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg

All references to the egg will now actually point to a directory in your site-packages containing the unzipped python files.  The new devappserver should be able to work with this.

Unsure how to unzip an egg in windows? See here (presuming you have Winzip or similar installed):
http://mail.python.org/pipermail/chicago/2007-July/002301.html